# Double unquoting for dynamically generated macros

Tags: macros, metaprogramming, elixir

Given the following:

```
  for fn_name <- [:foo, :bar, :baz] do
    defmacro unquote(fn_name)(do: inner) do
      fn_name = unquote(fn_name) # <--- Why?
      quote do
        IO.puts "#{unquote(fn_name)} called"
        unquote(inner)
      end
    end
  end
```

What's the reason for `fn_name = unquote(fn_name)`? If I omit this line, it's a compile error. What's the reason for this "double" unquoting?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's simplify the example a little bit:

```
for fn_name <- [:foo, :bar, :baz] do
  defmacro unquote(fn_name)(do: inner) do
    fn_name = unquote(fn_name) # <--- Why?
    quote do
      {unquote(fn_name), unquote(inner)}
    end
  end
end
```

In the example above, because quote is returning a tuple with two unquoted elements, it is equivalent to:

```
for fn_name <- [:foo, :bar, :baz] do
  defmacro unquote(fn_name)(do: inner) do
    fn_name = unquote(fn_name) # <--- Why?
    {fn_name, inner}
  end
end
```

Now it is easier to understand what happens if you don't `unquote(fn_name)` before: the variable `fn_name` simply wouldn't exist inside the macro definition. Remember that all `def`s (def, defp, defmacro, etc) start a new variable scope, so if you want to use fn_name inside, you need to define it somehow.

The other property we are seeing in this code is that Elixir will stop unquoting when it sees a `quote`. So in the quote above, `unquote` won't be unquoted when the macro is defined but rather when the macro is executed, which also explains why the variable is required to be defined inside the macro.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time! This makes perfect sense, and I have additional tools now to reason about metaprogramming :D

Answer (score 2):

It's because of **Hygiene**.

Elixir has the concept of macro *hygiene*. Hygiene means that variables, imports, and aliases that you define in a macro do not leak into the caller’s own definitions.

```
for fn_name <- [:foo, :bar, :baz] do
    defmacro unquote(fn_name)(do: inner) do
      fn_name = unquote(fn_name) # <-- This is macro's context
      quote do
        IO.puts "#{unquote(fn_name)} called" # <-- This is caller's context
        unquote(inner)
      end
    end
  end
```

You should read **Hygiene Protects the Caller’s Context** from Chris McCord's Metaprogramming Elixir book

Comment: Thank you! Thinking in terms of macro vs caller context is very helpful!